# Как передать значение переменной в t.slug IN()?

Tags: php, wordpress

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы в админке при создании/редактировании записи в рубриках была только та рубрика которая соответствует компании автора.

```
function post_editor_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ), true ) ) {

        //$all_company = include_once('php/all_company.php');

        $all_company = array(
            'company_1' => 'news_1',
            'company_2' => 'news_2',
            'company_3' => 'news_3'
        );

        //$user_company = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_company', true );
        $user_company = 'company_2';
        $cat_company = $all_company[$user_company];

        if ( $cat_company ) {
            $exclusions = "{$exclusions} AND t.slug IN ('".$cat_company."')";
        }

    }   
        return $exclusions;

}
 
add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'post_editor_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2 );
```

```
$exclusions = "{$exclusions} AND t.slug IN ('".$cat_company."')";
//получаю вместо списка рубрик news_2news_2
```

```
//$exclusions = "{$exclusions} AND t.slug IN ('news_2')";
//получаю вместо списка рубрик news_2news_2
```

без if

```
$exclusions = "{$exclusions} AND t.slug IN ('".$cat_company."')";
//получаю вместо списка рубрик news_2news_2
```

```
$exclusions = "{$exclusions} AND t.slug IN ('news_2')";
// Получаю нужную рубрику
```

Comment: вринципе код рабочий, единственное что еще можно сделать так это уточнить какую именно таксономию вы хотите фильтровать. так же не совсем понятно почему у вас в запросе несколько раз встречается параметр пустой параметр IN, вы еще гдето добавляете эти параметры? ну и само собой не одной таксономии нет потому что у вас в запросе есть проверка на пустой слаг таксономии (AND t.slug IN ('')) а этого быть не может, поэтому вы и не находите их

Comment: AND t.slug IN ('news_2') AND t.slug IN ('') AND t.slug IN ('')
//не показывает ни одной рубрики

Эта строка результат вывода echo $exclusions; для проверки. при этом рубрики исчезают все. А написать слаг вместо переменной то результат будет AND t.slug IN ('news_2') и при этом все рубрики исчезают а нужная остается и все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберните строку

```
$exclusions = "{$exclusions} AND t.slug IN ('". $cat_company ."')";
```

в `if`

```
if ( $cat_company ) {
    $exclusions = "{$exclusions} AND t.slug IN ('". $cat_company ."')";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это сработало как в рабочем варианте, но... Я получил результат AND t.slug IN ('news_2') но все рубрики остались на месте. Т.е цель не достигнута. Теперь даже если слаг написать вручную вместо переменной это также не работает и все рубрики на месте.

Comment: Ничего не понял, если честно. Особенно про "не работает вручную". Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, возможно так будет понятнее. Во всех вариантах я получаю news_2 что равно слагу рубрики news_2. Но только если я укажу news_2 тогда это работает а если как переменную то не работает.

Comment: Да все таки с if работает. Как только я переписал массив внутри без инклюда файла, получил нужный результат.